# Insert Header Line into text file? C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a text file that displays information retrieved from an sql database.  Is there a way to insert a line on top of the data that will be used as a header?

Here is the code for the text file part.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
   sb.AppendLine(row[0].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[1].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ') + "," + row[2].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[3].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ')
   + "," + row[4].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[5].ToString().PadRight(15, ' ') + "," + row[6].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[7].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ')
   + "," + row[8].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[9].ToString().PadRight(6, ' ') + "," + row[10].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[11].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ')
   + "," + row[12].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[13].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[14].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[15].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
   + "," + row[16].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[17].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[18].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[19].ToString().PadRight(7, ' ')
   + "," + row[20].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[21].ToString().PadRight(11, ' ') + "," + row[22].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[23].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
   + "," + row[24].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[25].ToString().PadRight(39, ' '));
}

using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(mypath + @"\CCC.txt")) outFile.Write(sb.ToString());
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Same way as you output rows you can output headers **before** `foreach` if that is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the idea of a bool for first line. Why not just append the header before the loop?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Header Line");
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
ppendLine(row[0].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[1].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ') + "," + row[2].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[3].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ')
                      + "," + row[4].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[5].ToString().PadRight(15, ' ') + "," + row[6].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[7].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ')
                      + "," + row[8].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[9].ToString().PadRight(6, ' ') + "," + row[10].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[11].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ')
                      + "," + row[12].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[13].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[14].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[15].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
                      + "," + row[16].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[17].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[18].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[19].ToString().PadRight(7, ' ')
                      + "," + row[20].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[21].ToString().PadRight(11, ' ') + "," + row[22].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[23].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
                      + "," + row[24].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[25].ToString().PadRight(39, ' ')) ;
    }
    using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(mypath + @"\CCC.txt")) outFile.Write(sb.ToString());
    myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the header line!!

```
bool firstline = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if(firstline)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Header Line");
        firstline = false;
    }
    sb.AppendLine(row[0].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[1].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ') + "," + row[2].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[3].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ')
                  + "," + row[4].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[5].ToString().PadRight(15, ' ') + "," + row[6].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[7].ToString().PadRight(4, ' ')
                  + "," + row[8].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[9].ToString().PadRight(6, ' ') + "," + row[10].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[11].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ')
                  + "," + row[12].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[13].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[14].ToString().PadRight(30, ' ') + "," + row[15].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
                  + "," + row[16].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[17].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[18].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ') + "," + row[19].ToString().PadRight(7, ' ')
                  + "," + row[20].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[21].ToString().PadRight(11, ' ') + "," + row[22].ToString().PadRight(1, ' ') + "," + row[23].ToString().PadRight(13, ' ')
                  + "," + row[24].ToString().PadRight(8, ' ') + "," + row[25].ToString().PadRight(39, ' ')) ;
}
using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(mypath + @"\CCC.txt")) outFile.Write(sb.ToString());
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks! Only my second day using c# so I'm still very new.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @chachi No worries. Just mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the header line, if you want the columns

```
bool firstheader=true;
for (int i = 0 ; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
  if (!firstheader)
     sb.Append(",");
  firstheader=false;
  sb.Append(dataTable.Columns[i]);
}
```